# applescript excel 2011 Save as Tab Delimited Text File

Tags: excel, applescript

I am trying to write an apple script that will save a particular file as a tab delimited text file.  The script creates the file however it create the file in a .xlxs format not .txt (despite the file extension).  When you create the file manually it bring up a warning

> "This workbook contains features the will not work or may be removed if you save it in hte selected format.  Do you want to continue?  To save the workbook in this file format, click Continue.  To preserve the workbook, click Cancel, and then save the workbook in a different file format"

Do I need to write something in my script to get past this warning and create the file in the correct, Tab Delimited Text, format?

Here is my script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set new_book to make new workbook
save workbook as new_book filename "test.txt" file format [text Mac file format]
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

I'm using El Capitain with Excel 2011 and I get no error message running your script. You may have something else different (?).

You can also try to tell Microsoft to not display alert :

```
Tell Application "Microsoft Excel" to set display alerts to false
```

Last comment: your save will save file "test.txt" in current default folder which can be anywhere. I suggest you to indicate clearly the path (i.e. : "Users:me:Desktop:test.txt")

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I think I was unclear.  If I open a new worksheet and save it selecting file format tab delimited text file, that is when I get the error message.  I do not get and error message when I run the script.  I'll try the not display alert line you suggest and let you know the results.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  The [ ] are not needed around the format.  The following code works perfect.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set new_book to make new workbook
save workbook as new_book filename "test.txt" file format text Mac file format
end tell
```